# Check constraint to prevent 2 or more rows from having numeric value of 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have a SQL table with a column called [applied], only one row from all rows can be applied ( have the value of 1) all other rows should have the value 0

Is there a check constraint that i can write to force such a case?

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: A regular check constraint will do fine, if you use NULL instead of 0. Otherwise you probably need a trigger.

Comment: If you use Postgres you can do that with a filtered index: `create unique index on the_table(applied)
where applied;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support filtered indexes:

```
create unique index unq_t_applied on t(applied) where applied = 1;
```

Comment: i changed t(id) to t(applied) and this works, thanks!. create unique index unq_t_applied on t(applied) where applied = 1;

Comment: @MaayanHope . . .Yes.  Thank you.  I was thinking of a different situation where you would want one value per group -- and I even got that explanation wrong.  Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use null instead of 0, it will be much easier.

Have a CHECK constraint to make sure the (non-null) value = 1. Also have a UNIQUE constraint to only allow a single value 1.

```
create table testtable (
    id int primary key,
    applied int,
    constraint applied_unique unique (applied),
    constraint applied_eq_1 check (applied = 1)
);
```

Core ANSI SQL, i.e. expected to work with *any* database.

Answer (score 0):

To know exactly how to write trigger that will help you an info of a database you use is needed.

You wil need a trigger where this will be your test control:

```
 SELECT COUNT(APPLIED) 
 FROM TEST
 WHERE APPLIED = 1
```

If it is > 0 then do not allow insert else allow.

Answer (score 0):

While this can be done with triggers and constraints, they probably require an index. Instead, consider a join table.

```
create table things_applied (
  id smallint primary key default 1,
  thing_id bigint references things(id) not null,
  check(id = 1)
);
```

Because the primary key is unique, [there can only ever be one row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141789/how-to-limit-maximum-number-of-rows-in-a-table-to-just-1).

The first is activated with an insert.

```
insert into things_applied (thing_id) values (1);
```

Change it by updating the row.

```
update things_applied set thing_id = 2;
```

To deactivate completely, delete the row.

```
delete things_applied;
```

To find the active row, join with the table.

```
select t.*
from things t
join things_applied ta on ta.thing_id = t.id
```

To check if it's active at all, count the rows.

```
select count(id) as active
from things_applied
```

[Try it.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2458bc5374200fa0709eb147084a0edb)